# Is this considered a model or a view object?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, language-agnostic

My application downloads images from the web and encloses them in custom Image objects. Using my Image class I can extract particular data from the images. That data is eventually presented to the user.

With the model-view-controller paradigm in mind, can my Image class be considered a model class or a view class?

Comment: you've got two correct answers here - the image class is a model class. Not sure who got it right first though. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered it yourself when you said "the data is eventually presented to the user".  The model is the programmatic representation that you can modify/manipulate/extract data from.  The view is the "presentation".  Your image class "eventually" gets presented.  That presentation is the view.  The image class is the model.

Answer (score 1):

It would be considered a model - a view is usually a UI template that a model is mapped to.

In a web-based MVC implementation the view is the HTML template into which the data from the model is populated for display.

Comment: Accepted Bal's answer because he's just starting out I think, but thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A ViewModel class should only contain properties and view spesific logic such as formatting, deciding which data should be visible and so on